# How to Stream Music from one system to another via Wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio, streaming

just tried out Microsoft's Mouse without Borders and found it really handy , as I am able to work on my Laptop while running other applications on my PC.

Would be really awesome , if I could have all the sounds from my laptop play on my PC's speakers. Its pretty obvious , that I dont want to plug in any more hardware to my laptop such as Airport Express / Line in etc

If i can transfer data over wifi , why cant i do the same with my audio.

Here is my use case - Pandora playing on my laptop (so that I can change the songs easily) , while the sound is playing over my HTPC elsewhere.

Comment: I think you should look at DLNA devices. I am not sure what Pandora is but Windows Media Player is DLNA compatible. I can control music playing on my HTPC from my laptop or my phone.

Answer (score 0):

There's a German freeware called [No23Live](http://no23.de/no23web/Live-Audio-broadcasting-webradio-stream-online-radio.aspx?live=1) I use for this problem.
It turns your computer sound output into a web stream. 
This stream is then available for any device in your home network.

The software and website are in German language, if that doesn't scare you,
you should be able to get it to run with the help of google translate.